# Why does the silverlight Datagrid not display the data?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, controls

In the below code below i get the SelectedItem  from the listbox and display its contents in the second datagrid.

If however i replace the listbox with the datagrid that is commented out, the data no longer shows in the second datagrid.  Any reason as to why the data only displays in the second datagrid when i use the listbox??

```
  <ListBox   Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding NonNavBarPricerLayouts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNonNavBarItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <!--<data:DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding NonNavBarPricerLayouts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNonNavBarItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                   SelectedIndex="-1" 
                   GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pricer Layout" Width="150">
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>              
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>

    </data:DataGrid>-->



    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,5,5,0" Text="Selected pricer layout contents:"/>
    <data:DataGrid Name="dgPricerLayoutDetail" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedNonNavBarItem.PricerDetails}" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                   SelectedIndex="-1" 
                   IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="None">

    </data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: From the looks of what you posted, it looks like you're binding to a different element.  In the list box, your ItemsSource is **Binding NonNavBarPricerLayouts** whereas in the DataGrid, you've changed your ItemsSource to **SelectedNonNavBarItem.PricerDetails** which I would presume must be empty by the name - nothing is selected. ;)

Comment: The ListBox and the commented out DataGrid bind to the same things.  If i run the code as is, the details are displayed in the Bottom Datagrid.  If i comment out the ListBox and Uncomment the Commented out dataGrid, no data appears in the Bottom datagrid

Comment: It works in SL 4 so my guess its a bug in SL3.  Im using SL3

Comment: Ensure then the the PricerDetails are an "ObservableCollection" and not just a "Collection".

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer just in case anyone else stumbles across this. I spent about 4 hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. I had a very similar situation to caa.

In SilverLight 3, a bound SelectedItem from one DataGrid as the ItemsSource for another DataGrid makes it so no data will show in the one with it as the ItemsSource. When I switched the 2nd one to a ListBox, my items would show. I could not figure out what I was doing wrong until I stumbled across this post and saw caa comment that it worked in SilverLight 4 but not 3. I found that my legacy project was a SilverLight 3 project and changing it to 4 fixed it.